# how to make row data to source and target zigzag using hive or pig

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-pig

**Input**

```
id,name,time
1,home,10:20
1,product,10:21
1,mobile,10:22
2,id,10:24
2,bag,10:30
2,home,10:21
3,keyboard,10:32
3,home,10:33
3,welcome,10:36
```

I want to make name column as source and target based on the below output.
Earlier I tried with `pig`

The steps are:

a=load-->b=asc->c=dec -> then join the data

I got the output like this

```
(1,home,10:20,1,product,10:21)
(2,bag,10:30,2,id,10:24)
(3,home,10:32,3,welcome,10:36)
```

**output**

```
1,home,product
1,product,mobile
2,id,bag
2,bag,home
3,keyboard,home
3,home,welcome
```

Comment: You have tagged sql, hive, pig and spark. How are you planning to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hive (and in Spark), you can use Window function LEAD :

```
with t as 
   ( select id, name, lead(name)  over (partition by id) as zigzag from table) 
select * from t where t.zigzag is not null
```

Should give you the output :

```
+---+--------+-------+
| id|    name| zigzag|
+---+--------+-------+
|  1|    home|product|
|  1| product| mobile|
|  2|     bag|   home|
|  2|    home|     id|
|  3|keyboard|   home|
|  3|    home|welcome|
+---+--------+-------+
```